# `from QTKit import *` causes a 'FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer' in PyObjC application

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I've been trying out PyObjC and I can't seem to get the QTKit imports to work.  If I import QTKit like so: `from QTKit import *` I get a flood of errors:

```
[Session started at 2009-11-13 21:03:49 -0600.]
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.671 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.673 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.673 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.674 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.681 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.682 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.692 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] NSInternalInconsistencyException - Error (1002) creating CGSWindow
2009-11-13 21:03:50.704 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.705 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.712 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.713 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.721 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.721 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
2009-11-13 21:03:50.722 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** -[NSRecursiveLock unlock]: lock (<NSRecursiveLock: 0x1c55c00> '(null)') unlocked when not locked
2009-11-13 21:03:50.723 WhyDoesntThisWork[16550:10b] *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

This happens even with no other code added to the application.  For example:  I can create a new cocoa/python project, add the Quicktime framework, open the generated delegate and add the line `from QTKit import *` , build and run and the errors flow.  Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/05/17/pyobjc-hello-world/).  Apparently QTKit cannot be imported until after the runloop has been established.